# Generate postback to specific method/event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, postback

I have a custom gridview, and i'm generating a postback event for onclick manually on RowDataBound. However, this postback ALWAYS goes to/expects a specific method on the row click.

Here's my current code to make that postback happen:

```
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(this.OnRowClick))
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", this.Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this.grid1, "Select$" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString()));
```

As you can see here, i've setup a property to my grid to ask which method to call when executing that postback... however, i cannot seem to find anywhere on the web how to specify in the _dopostback call WHICH method to call... it always, without exception, expects this method:

```
grid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, eventargs e)
```

But I don't want that. I want it to go to whatever method name is contained in the property OnRowClick.

Here's how things are currently setup for the visual people:

that's just it... i'm not sure. I am a visual person so maybe this will help a bit for everyone as well:

> Custom Control Setup (minified version):
>
> [ Some other controls
>
> -= A gridview =-
>
> Some other controls]
>
> [(Control Event Property)
>
> OnRowClick Event (GridViewRow eventarg)]
>
> [(Control Event Wireup)
>
> if(OnRowClick!=null)
>
> this.GridView1.SelectedIndexChanged += InternalMethod(...)
>
> [(InternalMethod(...))
>
> GridViewRow row = this.GridView1.SelectedRow;
>
> if(OnRowClick!=null)
>
> OnRowClick(row);]]

So far so good... no problems whatsoever... BUT... when i set it up like this:

> HtmlPage
>
> -> Custom Control(mygrid)
>
> ---> mygrid.OnRowClick += SomePageMethod(GridViewRow row)
>
> ------> SomePageMethod never, ever, gets called... like... never...

Since i have built my control as a composite control, i can't step through its internal code to debug, so i can't tell why it's not happening... :S please please help me bubble up this event properly!

Custom Control Code:

```
    this.grid1.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(grid1_SelectedIndexChanged);

    void grid1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridViewRow row = this.grid1.SelectedRow;
        if(this.OnRowClick!=null)
            OnRowClick(this.grid1, row);

    }

    #region Events
    public delegate void RowClickEventHandler(object sender, GridViewRow SelectedRow);
    [Category("Events")]
    [Description("This event fires when a row is clicked, if it is defined")]
    public event RowClickEventHandler OnRowClick;
    #endregion
```

Web page code:

```
this.pgrSummary.OnRowClick += new SimplePager.SimplePager.RowClickEventHandler(pgrSummary_OnRowClick);
```

And that methode never gets called...

Comment: Is it that the onclick event is set a render time so using a method to calculate it dynamically wont work? Could the method that gets called work out the logic and then call the click handler you want?

Comment: that's just it... i'm not sure. I am a visual person so maybe this will help a bit for everyone as well: